# I have mechanic licence from Turkey.Is there any way to easly get or change mechanic technician licenses in Alberta or Ontario

Tags: licensing, ontario, car, alberta, automotive

I am auto mechanic.  I came to Canada 5 years ago I wanna do my job here but almost all places saying you need 4 years and every year 1500 hours and 8 weeks school than you can get license.  Is there any way to avoid that time or make it Less with my turkish mechanic license and experience?  Thank you .

Comment: https://www.immigration.ca/automotive-mechanics-automotive-technicians/ — talk to someone about it

Comment: There should be institutions in Canada that deal with the foreign qualifications of immigrants. Canada is pretty open immigration wise. They should have mechanisms that credit foreign qualifications.

Comment: This might be a better question for [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 1):

In Ontario, you can apply for a [Trade Equivalency Assessment.](https://www.skilledtradesontario.ca/experienced-workers/trade-equivalency-assessment/)

> Skilled Trades Ontario’s Trade Equivalency Assessment is the first step towards obtaining a Certificate of Qualification for experienced workers who have not completed an Ontario apprenticeship but who have equivalent skills and experience. The Trade Equivalency Assessment determines whether you can challenge the certifying exam for a trade. If successful in the exam, you would pay a fee to be issued a Certificate of Qualification in that trade.

In other words, this is a certification that you've gained practical skills and have enough work experience (which I would expect to be about [four years](https://www.skilledtradesontario.ca/trade-information/automotive-service-technician/), since that's what's required for people starting from scratch via the Ontario  apprenticeship system.)  You then also have to take a certifying exam.

In Alberta, you can apply for the [Trades Qualifier - Work Experience](https://tradesecrets.alberta.ca/become-certified/qualify-based-on-work-experience/) program.  For an [Automotive Service Technician,](https://tradesecrets.alberta.ca/trades-in-alberta/profiles/009/) this requires:

> - A minimum of 72 months AND 9,360 hours of work experience.
> - A successful theory exam.
> - A Trades Competency Verification (TCV) *[a practical exam — ed.]*